What is the meaning of 8va combined with the bracket?
I am learning from Bastien Piano for Adults 1, and on page 57 there is 8va mark (which is explained) but at the bottom of the page, there is additional bracket. What is the meaning of the bracket (or bracket+8va, I am not sure if bracket alone has meaning).


There are two separate symbols.

The 8va plus dotted line mean to play that passage one octave lower than written.
The solid bracket under the final note is a (damper) pedal indication. You press down the right-most pedal at the down-stroke, hold through the horizontal line, and release at the up-stroke. That is, hold the pedal for the duration of that note.


Thank you very much, I was afraid it is some kind of alteration of 8va symbol.
